# How do I change the default path for Bazel when multiple version installed?

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I got a message that I needed to upgrade to the newest version of Bazel to build Tensorflow. I followed the instructions for installing bazel using apt-get and it says I have 0.7.0 installed.

However when I issue the command "**bazel version**", I am still seeing the older 0.4.5 version installed. When I issue "**whereis bazel**" I get the following results:
**bazel: /usr/bin/bazel /etc/bazel.bazelrc /usr/local/bin/bazel /usr/local/lib/bazel**

The version at /usr/bin/bazel is the newest version 0.7.0.  However the version at /usr/local/bin/bazel is the older version 0.4.5.

I am somewhat new to Linux, but assume there has got to be a way to change the pointer for the path for when I call bazel directly.  Is this assumption correct?  Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` return you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just remove your installation under /usr/local/bin/bazel which was probably installed with an older shell installer: `sudo rm /usr/local/bin/bazel`

Comment: Thanks Damien!  I thought I needed to keep it around for other dependencies.  This worked perfectly and was about as easy as it gets.